# How to Auto Resize the subViews in a View which is converted into UIView from Xamarin Forms View?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working to convert a Xamarin Forms View into a Native UIView using the below code snippet. But the size of view could not be get from the Xamarin forms View, and also the subviews could not be auto resized when the view is Resized.

I have tried using AutoResizingMask but it did not worked.Any help is much appreciated.

```
public void CustomView(int pageIndex, View customView, Point offset)
{
 var visualElement = Platform.CreateRenderer(customView);
 visualElement.NativeView.Frame = new CGRect((int)offset.X, (int)offset.Y, 
 (int)100, (int)100);
 visualElement.NativeView.AutoresizingMask = 
 UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
 visualElement.NativeView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;
 visualElement.NativeView.AutosizesSubviews = true;
 visualElement.Element.Layout(new CGRect((int)offset.X, (int)offset.Y, 
 (int)100, (int)100).ToRectangle());
 visualElement.Element.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
 visualElement.NativeView.AutosizesSubviews = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the code below to convert forms view to native, it works fine on the iOS platform:

```
public UIView CreateCustomView(View customView, CGRect size)
{
    var renderer = Platform.CreateRenderer(customView);

    renderer.NativeView.Frame = size;

    renderer.NativeView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
    renderer.NativeView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;

    renderer.Element.Layout(size.ToRectangle());

    var nativeView = renderer.NativeView;

    nativeView.SetNeedsLayout();

    return nativeView;
}
```

Here is my sample for you referring to: https://github.com/landl0526/LoadingFormsViewDemo.git

Comment: Xamarin Forms  view includes a stackpanel with a button and image . After converted into native UIView when I resize the view , the button and image were not resized accordingly.

Comment: @WhiteWalker Can you offer a sample so that I can see your issues on my side?